# Unmarshaling failed, and it reports "invalid character '\x00' in string literal"

Tags: go

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
$ go version
go1.19.1
```

#### Does this issue reproduce with the latest release?

YES

#### What operating system and processor architecture are you using (`go env`)?

Linux

#### What did you do?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func UnescapeUnicode(uContent string) (string, error) {
    content := strings.Replace(strconv.Quote(uContent), `\\u`, `\u`, -1)
    text, err := strconv.Unquote(content)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return text, nil
}

func main() {
    v := "{\"aa\":\"some\\u0000\"}"
    v2, _ := UnescapeUnicode(v)
    var m = make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(v2), &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

```
map[aa:some]
```

#### What did you see instead?

```
invalid character '\x00' in string literal
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Please describe what you try to do.

Comment: Yes. This code doesn't really mean anything, I just want to show you how it reports an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the main method as below by removing `UnescapeUnicode` function.

```golang
func main() {
    v := "{\"aa\":\"some\\u0000\"}"
    var m = make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

**Note:**

- `\u0000` is an unicode. In order to be included `\u0000` in the string, `\u0000` should be replaced with `\\u0000`.
- Double quote (`"`) is a reserved characters and can not be used in JSON and must be properly escaped to be used in strings. For that, double quote should be replaced with `\"`.
- You don't need to mannully handle **Special Characters Escaping**. It will be handled by `json.Unmarshal`.

Comment: Thank you. But my real scenario is that the character on system A is something like {\"aa\":\"some\\u0000\"}, and when it's synchronized to system B it goes through the UnescapeUnicode function. My job is to take it from system B and do some processing, and I'll convert it to a map, but it will report this error.

Comment: And I don't know why go json.Unmarshal can't decode \x00